# Java code running faster on Mac with slower processor than on my Windows computer?

Tags: java, windows, macos, performance

I couldnt find any answer to this so I thought I'd ask in here.

I have a MacBook with a Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4870HQ CPU @ 2.50GHz and a Windows computer with an i7-4790K 4ghz cpu.

I wrote some Java code which is running 6 threads on both machines with a long running task iterating over an ArrayList with a normal for-loop which is the same every time except each time the ArrayList gets a little bit shorter so the time naturally becomes shorter each time the method runs. However, running it on both my MacBook and Windows computer there is a noticable difference in the time it takes for them to run the code and my MacBook is winning each time with around 1 minute or more out of the around 12-13 minutes it takes to run the method (at this point).

Neither of the cpus are running at 100% and both computers have a lot of unused RAM.

I hope you can help and let me know if there is a way I can provide more information. :)

Comment: Do you have I/O operations in the loop that may depend on different OS-specific implementations? For example Mac's Filesystem could be faster than Windows' ...

Comment: Other than iterating over the ArrayList there are some connections to a MySQL database which is on the Windows computer, the queries are simple select and update statements for controlling concurrency between the threads.

Basically what the loop does is it compares each row with the rest of the rows after it to make sure two rows are not compared twice. So I use the database to make sure the same row is not compared twice.

Comment: Check if your JVM settings are the same.

Comment: As far as I can see they have the same settings. I just tried to update the JDK to the same version on both computers, still seem to be the same.

Comment: Saying “i7” doesn’t help anything to predict the performance. Intel uses that name for **seven** CPU generations now. So your Windows computer uses a CPU of the fourth generation with four cores (eight with hyperthreading), which might be using less than 100% with six threads, but we have no information about the MacBook’s actual CPU to make a comparison. Not even the clock speed says anything, as it’s likely a mobile CPU with adaptive clock speed that could change by a factor of almost two.

Comment: So I found the exact model of the CPU in my MacBook and it is an Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4870HQ CPU @ 2.50GHz.

Answer (score 1):

I would start by checking the specs of the memory on each machine. As a rule Apple tends to put the fastest RAM it can in its machines.

If it's not the RAM, you should check that the JVM is configured the same: if the heap space is smaller on the Windows PC, it's probably spending that extra minute garbage collecting.

Other than that, it must be something like context switching being faster on the Mac, but I've never heard before anybody suggesting that OS X is intrinsically faster than Windows.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the answer. I just checked the RAM specs: The Windows has 4x8 gb 1866mhz DDR3 and the Mac has 2x8 gb 1600mhz DDR3. 

The max heap size for the code is set to 8gb and they are each using around 1.3gb heap according to jvisualvm.

Comment: I looked through my code again and it came to my mind that I at some point had added a System.gc() in a finally clause in the loop to see how it worked. I have removed it now and the Windows seems to be a tiny bit faster than the MacBook now, so could it be, that the GC is faster on the MacBook compared to the Windows?

Comment: Given the hardware specs of the processor and memory, I would expect the Windows version to be significantly faster.The RAM is more than 12% faster and the CPU is more than 30% faster. At this point I have no explanation for your performance figures.