# Java application running significantly faster on Mac OS than Windows

Tags: java, windows, macos, performance

I am trying to run a Java program which finds Poly divisible numbers. However, I have found that it is significantly slower on my Windows computer in comparison to the speed it runs at on a Macbook Pro.

There was another question I found here: [Java code running faster on Mac with slower processor than on my Windows computer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42248507/java-code-running-faster-on-mac-with-slower-processor-than-on-my-windows-compute) with a similar problem, however it has no conclusive answer to why it is slower.

Do you know any reason why this may be and how this could be fixed.

**Windows Specs:**

- i7 7700k @ 4.2 GHz (4 Cores, 8 threads)
- 16 GB RAM @ 3000MHz. (DDR4)
- Timings: https://gist.github.com/JosephBywater/f79f5e8277d148c26804c85c2c6a399a

**Macbook Pro Early 2015**

- Intel i5 (unknown model, possibly i5 5257U) @ 2.7 GHz
- 8 GB RAM @ 1867 MHz. (DDR3)
- Timings: https://gist.github.com/oliverdunk/ad3dd134b653c43c9928

Code https://github.com/oliverdunk/Polydivisbles

Comment: Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on [Super User](https://superuser.com/).

Comment: It is also a question about the performance of Java - maybe a code issue?Although, would you be able to transfer it to Super User or would I need to repost it myself?

Comment: Perhaps you'd want to ask how to profile your Java applications and the JVM. That would be on topic, I hope.